# How to trim Spring Boot error logs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging

I'm looking if it's possible to reduce/trim logs thrown by Spring Boot to something like:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: null
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.myproject.api.controllers.MyController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d7e0b073.getByZipcode(<generated>) ~[myproject-0.1.0.jar!/:0.1.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    [...76 lines omitted]
```

Is it possible to achieve something similar with the defaults provided by spring boot from the `spring-boot-starter` dependency?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you like to reduce the length of the stacktraces being logged?

Comment: @MateuszMrozewski correct, to display the error plus some additional lines, if possible.

Comment: In general I would advise not to do it as the full stack trace may reveal some important information. Without it it might be hard to figure out the root cause of your problem. So one approach could be to have one appender that logs the complete stack traces and another configured as described by Tomasz Nurkiewicz http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/03/filtering-irrelevant-stack-trace-lines.html

Comment: @MateuszMrozewski this looks very promising, I'll check if that works and I'll advise how it goes. Thanks!